# Joining a Table to Itself with Null Values

Tags: mysql, join, null

I believe there should be a simple way to do this but I'm stuck here! I've read 20+ pages on here and elsewhere but couldn't find what I want.

I have one single table with few thousands of rows and tens of columns, but to simplify let's imaging the following table `qu` is my data:

```
+----+-----+-----+------+
| id | PID | AID | Data |
+----+-----+-----+------+
|  1 | A   |   1 |   56 |
|  2 | A   |   2 |  234 |
|  3 | B   |   1 |   23 |
|  4 | B   |   2 |   78 |
|  5 | B   |   3 |   65 |
|  6 | C   |   2 |   89 |
|  7 | C   |   3 |   74 |
+----+-----+-----+------+
```

I want to have a query that generates the following results:

```
+-----+-----+------+
| PID | AID | Data |
+-----+-----+------+
| A   |   1 | 56   |
| A   |   2 | 234  |
| A   |   3 | NULL |
| B   |   1 | 23   |
| B   |   2 | 78   |
| B   |   3 | 65   |
| C   |   1 | NULL |
| C   |   2 | 89   |
| C   |   3 | 74   |
+-----+-----+------+
```

Basically I want the query to fill all the missing `AID` for `PID`s and add `NULL` or `NA` for their `Data` values. I can achieve this by doing loops outside MySQL but it's very slow as I need to run individual queries for every single `PID` and `AID` combination to get the `Data` value.

Here is one of my latest tries with no success!

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `PID`
    FROM
        `qu`
    GROUP BY
        `PID`
) `a`
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `AID`
    FROM
        `qu`
    GROUP BY
        `AID`
) `b`
ON
    `a`.`id` = `b`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `qu` `c` ON
    `a`.`id` = `c`.`id` AND `b`.`id` = `c`.`id`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a calendar table approach here:

```
SELECT
    q1.PID,
    q2.AID,
    q3.Data   -- or use COALESCE(q3.Data, 'NA') AS Data
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PID FROM qu) q1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT AID FROM qu) q2
LEFT JOIN qu q3
    ON q3.PID = q1.PID AND
       q3.AID = q2.AID
ORDER BY
    q1.PID,
    q2.AID;
```

The idea here is that we generate all possible combinations of `PID` and `AID` using the cross join between the distinct subqueries aliased as `t1` and `t2`.  Then, we left join with your actual `qu` table, which either brings in the data if available, or else `NULL` if not available.

Comment: WOW Tim, you're awesome! Never knew about `cross join`. Thanks! I spent more than 2 days for this! :)

Comment: How can I get custom defined values instead of `NULL` such as `NA`?